# Does Windows XP (and above) handle a large number of installed fonts well?

Tags: windows, fonts

In the early NT days, just having a large number of fonts installed GREATLY decreased performance overall.

Is this still the case on Windows XP Pro SP3?  I have a client that would like to install several CDs worth of fonts onto their system and I advised some caution.  They would rather have the fonts on the system instead of having to fumble around the cd's to find them while working.

Any differences if the user were to go to Windows 7?

What do you all say?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a sysadmin question.  Will the user have a font manager/font suitcase?  There are lots of them.  It sure seems like you would get a better answer on doctype or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or maybe superuser.

Answer (score 2):

It will take a lot longer to load Photoshop and other Adobe products, but I've seen systems with graphic designers with > 1k fonts and I haven't had any complaints.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you mean handled.
I have almost 2k fonts on my pc stored on a hard drisk, not an SSD, and it causes painfully slow freezing when opening a font select dialog box. However, if I know the name of the font I can just use that and the computer doesn't have to bother using all of them.

So it works in a way if you know them all.
Note as well that fonts and a windows installed on a solid state drive may well load much faster